# iClusterPlus error for clustering HNSC TCGA data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, head

I'm doing clustering for HNSC TCGA dataset using iClusterPlus package

I have two errors

First

```
   **fit.single=iClusterPlus(dt1=df_m_tong1,dt2=df_c_tong1,dt3=df_e_tong1,
                        type=c("binomial","gaussian","gaussian"),
                        lambda=c(0.04,0.61,0.90),K=2,maxiter=10)**
```

Error in dataType(dt1, type[1], K) :
Error: some columns of binomial data are made of categories not equal to 2, which must be removed.

But, I have binomial typed mutation data

Second,

```
  **for(k in 1:5){
  cv3.fit = tune.iClusterPlus(cpus=5,dt1=df_m_tong1,dt2=df_c_tong1,dt3=df_e_tong1,
                             type=c("binomial","gaussian","gaussian"),K=k,n.lambda=185, 
                             scale.lambda=c(0.05,1,1),maxiter=20)
  save(cv3.fit, file=paste("cv3.fit.k",k,".Rdata",sep=""))
  }**
```

185  points of lambdas are used to tune parameters.
Begin parallel computation
End parallel computation
185  points of lambdas are used to tune parameters.
Begin parallel computation
End parallel computation
185  points of lambdas are used to tune parameters.
Begin parallel computation
End parallel computation
185  points of lambdas are used to tune parameters.
Begin parallel computation
End parallel computation
185  points of lambdas are used to tune parameters.
Begin parallel computation
End parallel computation
Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(1:nrow(ud), FUN = function(x) iClusterPlus(dt1, dt2,  :
185 function calls resulted in an error
2: In mclapply(1:nrow(ud), FUN = function(x) iClusterPlus(dt1, dt2,  :
185 function calls resulted in an error
3: In mclapply(1:nrow(ud), FUN = function(x) iClusterPlus(dt1, dt2,  :
185 function calls resulted in an error
4: In mclapply(1:nrow(ud), FUN = function(x) iClusterPlus(dt1, dt2,  :
185 function calls resulted in an error
5: In mclapply(1:nrow(ud), FUN = function(x) iClusterPlus(dt1, dt2,  :
185 function calls resulted in an error

After that, I couldn't proceed any further

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for the first error I think you should use 'binomial' type for all dt:
type=c("binomial","binomial","binomial")
For the second issue - did you install parallel? Maybe this is an issue.